# How to make elements in single line?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap in my project.

The width of the area is 350px.

I have this html elements:

```
   <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-xs-5" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="" ng-options="">
                    <option value="">- authority-</option>
                </select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is [plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/92z54z04/586/).

How can I make search box and dropdown list in one line.

Comment: You could use `float: left` for the first `input-group`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need css to fix this, you can do it with bootstrap styles.

Wrap the form in a 12 wide container (col-lg-12) and wrap each input in a 6 wide container (col-lg-6). (For simplicities sake I only used desktop size in the example)

This would look like:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
   <!-- start form -->
   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- input -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- input -->
   </div>
   <!-- end form -->
</div>
```

That way bootstrap will cut the screen in half (12 / 2 = 6) and put the input box in there.

To make it work with your code have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92z54z04/589/)

**Note** *I added col-lg, col-md, col-sm and col-xs to make them appear on the same line regardless of screen size.*

**EDIT:**
To put all of this in another panel use:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
     <!--    form row -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/92z54z04/596/

Comment: Thanks for post.Any idea how can I wrap the elements in frame?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question :)
What frame do you want them wrapped in? 
Did you take a look at the fiddle? it has more code in it than my example.

Comment: yes, I looked at the fiddle.I want to put the elements in some frame for example in panel to make it look batter.but it dosent work do you have any adia why it's not work?.

Answer (score 1):

`.input-group` are table displayed, so:

```
.input-group {
  display: inline-table;
}
```

will solve your problem.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92z54z04/587/)

Comment: This will change ALL elements with the ".input-group" class, no way of knowing what else this little bit of css might do to the application. It would be better to use just HTML elements (bootstrap col's) to make this work. Take a look at my Answer which doesn't use any extra CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="search"/>

            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>

    </div>

    <select class="form-group"    ng-model="builderStep1.inspectionArchiveData.DomainId"  ng-options="item.Id as item.Description for item in builderStep1.lookups.domain">
                <option value="">- authority-</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with bootstrap easily by using col-xs-6 property

here is the working code:

```
    <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-xs-6">

        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="builderStep1.inspectionArchiveData.DomainId" ng-options="item.Id as item.Description for item in builderStep1.lookups.domain">
                    <option value="">- authority-</option>
                </select>
        </div>
</div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend bootstrap to allow a select element inside your input group.
This depends on your usecase if it is intuitive, but I think this may be a good looking option to evaluate.
You basically copy and paste some of bootstraps style to make the select element fit into a input group.
If you have control over the sass, less files, you may be able to do it cleaner than I did.

```css
.input-group-select:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.input-group-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.input-group-select>select {
  border-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
}

.input-group-btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)>.btn {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
}

.input-group-select:last-child>select {
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.input-group-sm>.input-group-select>select {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-xs-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
    <div class="input-group-select">
      <select ng-model="builderStep1.inspectionArchiveData.DomainId" ng-options="item.Id as item.Description for item in builderStep1.lookups.domain">
                      <option value="">- authority-</option>
              </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-xs-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
    <div class="input-group-select">
      <select ng-model="builderStep1.inspectionArchiveData.DomainId" ng-options="item.Id as item.Description for item in builderStep1.lookups.domain">
                      <option value="">- authority-</option>
              </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-xs-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-select">
      <select class="select" ng-model="builderStep1.inspectionArchiveData.DomainId" ng-options="item.Id as item.Description for item in builderStep1.lookups.domain">
                      <option value="">- authority-</option>
              </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use style in div:

```
 display:inline-table;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ankitg1602/mqnrmLjb/1/

Comment: it will break the search box, since the search button is set as `display: table-cell`.